# How to use whitelisted modifier keys on action

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use the alt or ctrl keys as modifiers on my click action.  I'm doing the same thing that is listed in the guides (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-whitelisted-modifier-keys) but it seems to have no effect.

Does anyone have any working examples of how to use modifiers with actions?  I'm using Ember v1.0.0-rc.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key name has changed since this [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2263) from `allowed-keys` to `allowedKeys`. See [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/action.js#L37) for more details.

Hope it helps

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work either.  However, just for kicks, I tried "ctrl" (I had previously only used "alt"), and it worked!  So...I tried "shift" and "meta" and they also worked.  Something broken with "alt" for Chrome maybe?

Comment: I created an issue and jsbin for this...can be found here... http://jsbin.com/udepug/1/edit ...and here... https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2729